# TikZ pgfplots reverse x axis values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, formatting, axis, csv

Yes, I know there are loads of examples on this site, but I haven't found anything that works for me.
I tried to reverse the x axis values with `x dir=reverse`, but what i get is this

[image]

How do I make the y-axis stay to the left, and the x-axis arrow point to the right?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
      legend pos=outer north east,
      legend cell align={left},
      grid=none,
      xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=near xticklabel},
      ymin=0,ymax=100,
      xmin=300,xmax=4500,
      axis lines = middle,
      %y axis line style = {stealth-},
      xtick={400,700,1000,1300,1600,1900,2200,2500,2800,3100,3400,3700,4000},
      ytick={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90},
      extra x ticks={0},
      extra y ticks={0},
                width=16cm,
                height=8cm,
      set layers,
      x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
      y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
      xlabel={$\bar{\nu}$;(\unit{cm^{-1}})},ylabel={Trasmittance}, 
      style={thick},
      x dir=reverse
                   ]              
            \addplot [verde,very thick,domain=350:4500]
            table[x=WN,y=Trasmittance,col sep=comma] {EtoxAmm_64_2.csv};
            
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I see what you want, but it's against all conventions, having increasing x-values to the left. Won't make you a lot of friends, in my view, unless there is really reason for it. // Bypass: calculate the inverse x-values instead, like (1/4000=0.00025) and use as unit [cm]. // If you insist on using such an axis, draw it by using ordinary tikz-commands, which is a bit more work to do.